# Using Groovy's CliBuilder to get option error when the option is not first argument

Tags: groovy

my question is :
when i pass the script with :
groovy MyScript.groovy -o mtest -f filetest
the script can get the -o option.
but when i change the place of the option.
groovy MyScript.groovy -f filetest -o mtest 
it can't get the option of -o

why?
do i miss something?

the groovy code is:

```
def cli = new CliBuilder()
            cli.with {
        usage: 'Self'
        h longOpt:'help', 'U should input a analyze script with -o dataFileName!'
        o longOpt:'output', 'The file which should be analyzed.', args:1, required:true
        f longOpt:'file', 'File'
    }
            def opt = cli.parse(args)
            def action
            if( args.length == 0) {
                    cli.usage()
                    return
            }
            if( opt.h ) {
                    cli.usage()
                    return
            }
            println(args);
            println(opt);
            println(opt.o);
groovy MyScript.groovy -f filetest -o mtest
```

print result is : 
[-f, filetest,-o,mtest]
groovy.util.OptionAccessor@66b51404
false

groovy MyScript.groovy -o mtest -f filetest
    print result is : 
[-o,mtest,-f, filetest]
groovy.util.OptionAccessor@66b51404
mtest

Comment: i'am confuse what happen:< i'am sure that if i pass some option not defined,the Parser will parse fail.

Answer (score 1):

Think you need to specify `args` on your `-f` option as well (as it takes an argument) ie:

```
def cli = new CliBuilder().with {
  usage: 'Self'
  h longOpt:'help', 'U should input a analyze script with -o dataFileName!'
  o longOpt:'output', 'The file which should be analyzed.', args:1, required:true
  f longOpt:'file', 'File', args:1
  it
}

def opt = cli.parse( args )

if( opt ) {
  println args
  println opt
  println opt.o
}
```